# CSS: size property in class for input tags

Tags: css, html-input

I have the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rich Home</title>  
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <style>
    body { background-color: Black; color: White; }
    h1 {text-align: center}
    .st{ color: Green; background-color: Yellow; size: "80"; type:"text" }
  </style>    
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Rich's Home Page</h1>
  <form action="https://google.com/search" method="get">
    Google: <input class=st name="q" autofocus>
    <input type="submit" value="=>">
  </form>
  <form action="https://duckduckgo.com" method="get">
    Duck: <input class=st name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="=>">
  </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

I've opened in Firefox, Chrome and Chromium. Color and background-color are applied to the two input boxs, but size is not. Why is that?

Edit in response to various answers comments. using the following line instead has no effect:

```
.st{ color: Green; background-color: Yellow; width: "600px"; type:"text" }
```

Comment: you need to specify px after the value - currently it's getting to `80` and being like "great - 80 what?" so it does nothing with it

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I've tried changing size to "400px", but it has no effect.

Comment: try using width then - size is scarcely used in css - more of a html attribute..

Comment: @RichOliver Change `"600px"` to simply `600px` (no quotes).

Comment: @HiddenHobbes that did it. I had tried width before I published the question and size with and without quotes, but not width without quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "size" property in CSS. It is tag attribute.
If you want to specify width or height of element using CSS - use:

```
.st {
    width: 80px;
}
```

AND you can't set element type using CSS. Set attributes instead:

```
<input class=st name="q" type="text" autofocus>
```

ALSO you can you can specify width with attribute:

```
<input class=st name="q" type="text" width="50" autofocus>
```

Comment: not true - size exists but isn't standard as it hardly ever works.. but it does exist

Comment: It is standard, and it is exist. As you can see in my example btw. But it's all up to you how to separate styles from structure. I suggest to not use "width" as attribute.

Comment: thats what I said.. your first line says "there is no 'size' property in CSS."...

Answer (score 0):

The attribute "size" doesn't exist in CSS,
you have to specify [width and height](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp)
`.st{ color: Green; background-color: Yellow; width: 80px; type:"text" }`

should work.

Comment: not true - size exists but isn't standard as it hardly ever works.. but it does exist

Answer (score 0):

check this you can simply define class for other text types like "input[type="number"] "

```css
input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 60%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="name" />
```